# What will happen if i call endTimedEvent without logging a timed event in flurry analytics Android?

Tags: android, flurry, timed-events

I am using flurry analytics for android.I want to log how much time user spends on each section of multitab view containig (for example) 5 tabs.thus i will have to use " endTimedEvent " for different sections.now i want to end the timer for all other tabs except the one which is selected.thus if i use endTimedEvent for all other tabs other than selected one will this raise an error.(because at a time only one timer will be activated ,so if we try to end a timer event which has not been started Will it raise an error.)